# Forward proxy reading request and response body

Tags: http, go, proxy, goroutine

I am implementing a forward proxy in Go and I have 2 features that need to do:

- Limit upload and download with a maximum configurable size.
- Get md5 and sha256 of download file with a maximum configurable size for DLP purposes

Both of these features require to read request and response body and processing that would affect largely in performance by causing high memory consumption and slow response time for client.

Currently my flow is to `ioutil.ReadAll` request and response body, get the Body size, md5 and sha256 checksum the response body, finally if we do not blocking anything, put the body back to the origin one for the client

I was wondering if there is any other best practice for handling these kind of things.

Comment: Hello, for working code but seeking for performance the question has to moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Regards

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader

Comment: you can shaXX/md5 without keeping all in memory. there is no penalty performance in reading the body, otherwise you can t sum it. for sure you can implement the required pipeline system that does not consume more memory than number of client * buffer size. teereader is useful for this.